# How to understand "Bacon is for sycophants, and products of incest"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In Borderlands2, [one says](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Patricia_Tannis_Quotes):

> Also, I require a new ventilator -- this lab smells of bacon. Bacon is
>   for sycophants, and products of incest.

It's quite strange to comment such a common food. Why she claims "Bacon is for sycophants". And is there any story about "bacon is products of incest"?

Does she just blame bacon or take a metaphor for something?

PS:

You can read that [wiki page](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Patricia_Tannis) to learn more about that character.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be about English.

Comment: @snailplane I just have no idea about which stackexchange site is proper for my question... Could please give me some advice?

Comment: This is not a language question but asking about the meaning of a story, which only the author would precisely know/reveal.

Comment: Although we can't get into the possible literary implications, your are right to wonder about this, since there seems to be no rational connection between sycophants and products of incest, or between them and bacon.  This isn't an idiom of any kind, just one person's musings. The "products of incest" is a swipe taken at so-called "hillbillies and hicks" living in mountainous regions of the southern parts of the US, who are stereotyped as people who marry their close cousins and produce offspring with their siblings and other close relatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the real world (the one you and I inhabit), bacon  has nothing innately to do with sycophants or products of incest. In the real world, spoken by a sane, non mentally incompetent person, the comments merely indicate that the speaker does not like bacon and therefore is insulting those people who do like bacon.

However, I don't know if a character described as autistic, whimsical and having "a tenuous grip on sanity" can be relied upon for any logical statement.

Comment: Later in the (total drivel, imho) source, I find *Your payment will further my research on Eridium. And my bacon addiction.* So most likely there *is* a contextual reference. I'm guessing the speaker I cited has some senior position that might lead to sycophants aping his "bacon addiction", but it's such sh*te I can't be bothered to investigate further.